# Why can't a single layer neural network not solve the AND problem?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I am playing around with simple neural networks using Pytorch and I am confused about something. I think it should be able to solve the AND problem, since it is linearly separable, but after optimizing the parameters keep growing and so does the error. It works when adding a sigmoid activation function after the linear layer but I don't think that should be necessary. Can someone explain? Here is the gist of the code:

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2, 1))`
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    pred_y = model(data_x)
    loss = loss_function(pred_y, data_y)
    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Here is what the data looks like:
[image]

Comment: What is `data_x`?

Comment: The points being linearly separable does not mean that you can linearly **interpolate** them exactly, as you are trying. It only means that one can make it so that the linear NN is positive on the examples classified as 1 and negative on those classified as zero.

Comment: I added a picture of the data, I don't think I need to add the code that defines it.

Comment: I don't get your explanation, I can manually define the weights of such a neural network so that it solves the problem, it's just that the optimizer doesn't find them.

Comment: How do these manually defined weights look like?

Comment: Assuming the output of the network is y = w1*x1 +w2*x2 + b, then the weights w=(1, 1) with bias b=-1.5 will give a positive output for the points in red and negative output for the points in blue. Adding an activation just makes it so that the output is bounded.

Comment: As I wrote: it's easy to get a function that is positive on the red points and negative on the blue ones (or vice versa). But you are using the square loss, meaning that you are telling the gradient descent algorithm "please make the NN attain **exactly** the value +1 on the red points and -1 on the blue points" (or whatever values you chose, maybe +1 and 0). This means that for example having a value -5 on the blue points is worse than having the value +1 on these. This is why your algorithm is not finding the NN you want it to find. Don't use square loss for classification.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now!